# Rails use a variable in view not defined in model / controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to use a variable in my view to take in a value from a text box, though that is not to be stored directly.

For example:

```
<%= text_field_tag :tempVar, NIL %>
```

The temp var is to be used in the controller to generate the actual value for the model. Say something like:

```
@controller_name.final_value = concatenate (params[:tempVar] + xyz)
```

Edited: Had that params wrong when posted.

Is this do-able ?

Also, the 2nd part of the question is, if I want to create a new view for the controller which is already present (with some views). How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

:tempVar variable may be available in the controller via params[]. Try this:

```
@controller_name.final_value = concatenate (params[:tempVar] + xyz)
```